# Using JSOUP to read Titles from Wikipedia's "All Pages" special page

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, wikipedia

I'm trying to read and print out all of the titles listed in the English Wikipedia. It has a special page, "All pages," that shows all of the pages in alphabetical order.

The issues I have :

- It starts with ! but I don't know where it ends.. All pages seems to keep continue through characters like Æ and I don't want those
- The titles are on numerous pages, so I need to reload the "next page" after I finish reading one page of titles
- I've not had any experience using jsoup, so I don't know what I'm doing

Comment: Why don't you just download [the dump of all article titles](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz)?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages - Returns a list of pages in a given namespace, ordered by page title.